# How to properly use <ui:repeat>

Tags: jsf, facelets, uirepeat

I am having an issue using `<ui:repeat>` in a JSF page. I have an `arrayList` that I am passing to it, however, it never iterates through to display the contents.

I know that there is content because when I do the exact same thing using a `<h:datatable>`, it displays the contents. So if someone could explain to me why this does not work using `<ui:repeat>` but does using `<h:datatable>`, that would be great.

Here is the `<h:datatable>` code:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{proposalAction.proposal.proposalCountries}" var="pc" rendered="#{proposalAction.proposal.proposalCountries !=null and proposalAction.proposal.proposalCountries.size() > 0}">
    <h:column>
        <img src="/resources/images/flags/#{utils.getValidCountryFlagDisplayCode(pc.country)}.png" title="#{pc.country.getDisplayName(localeSelector.locale)}" alt="#{pc.country.getDisplayName(localeSelector.locale)}" width="20" />      
        &#160;
        <h:outputText value="#{pc.country.getDisplayName(localeSelector.locale)}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And here is the code using the `<ui:repeat>` code:

```
<ul>
    <ui:repeat items="#{proposalAction.proposal.proposalCountries}" var="pc" rendered="#{proposalAction.proposal.proposalCountries !=null and proposalAction.proposal.proposalCountries.size() > 0}">
        <li>
            <img src="/resources/images/flags/#{utils.getValidCountryFlagDisplayCode(pc.country)}.png" title="#{pc.country.getDisplayName(localeSelector.locale)}" alt="#{pc.country.getDisplayName(localeSelector.locale)}" width="20" />      
            &#160;<h:outputText value="#{pc.country.getDisplayName(localeSelector.locale)}" />
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

As you can see, they are identical. The datatable displays the countries, and yet the repeater doesn't display anything within the `<ul>` ... I am at a loss... please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have proper getters and setters then try using `#{pc.country.displayName}` as a value to your `h:outputText` tag. `ui:repeat` does not have `items` attribute, so use `value` instead. I am assuming `displayName` is a property of `Country` of your main list. And you can write your specific `Locale` logic inside getter.

This should work:

```
<ul>
    <ui:repeat value="#{proposalAction.proposal.proposalCountries}" var="pc" rendered="#{proposalAction.proposal.proposalCountries !=null and proposalAction.proposal.proposalCountries.size() > 0}">
        <li>
            <h:outputText value="#{pc.country.displayName}" />
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

Make such adjustments to your `img` tag too.
You should also put the logic for `rendered` in backend bean and use single boolean here on UI. such as `redered="#{displayCountries}`.